# How to click on Cancel on a windows explorer that displays when a upload button is clicked on a web page using Selenium WebDriver with Java

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am very new to Selenium WebDriver with Java. There is a Upload button on a job portal. When I click on that button windows explorer is displayed to choose the file. there are open and cancel buttons on this window. i want to select the cancel button. since it is a windows explorer i cannot inspect the cancel button. how do we write the code for cancelling the button. Thanks in advance.

```
driver.get("https://my.indeed.com/resume?from=gnav-homepage&co=US&hl=en_US");

driver.manage().window().maximize();

Thread.sleep(3000);

driver.findElement(

By.xpath("//[@id='container']/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/button")).click();
```

[image: Screenshot of the issue]

Answer (score 1):

I do not have Java programming skills. I hope the below python code is easy to translate. In my opinion, combining windows action with selenium calls is often flaky.

There is a hidden element called 'upload resume button', you can change the attribute value to see it on the UI, use the send keys method on the element to upload the resume.

```
 from selenium.webdriver import Remote, DesiredCapabilities

 driver = Remote(desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
 driver.get('https://my.indeed.com/resume?from=gnav-homepage&co=US&hl=en_US')

 driver.execute_script(
     "document.getElementById('upload-resume-button').setAttribute('class', '')"
 )

upload_your_resume = driver.find_element_by_id('upload-resume-button')
upload_your_resume.send_keys(r'C:\test\resume.docx')
```

The above code worked in my local.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is you cant, but if you want to upload a local file you can use send_keys on the input field, sending the file path.

Here is a python exemple:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("IdOfInputTypeFile").send_keys(os.getcwd()+"/image.png")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Robot class to simulate native keyboard and mouse actions to interact with windows based pop-ups.
The shortcut to close any opened window is: “Alt + Space +C” – Closes the focused window.

```
Robot rb = new Robot();
rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT); 
rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_C);
rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_C);
rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
```